# setting up a search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Now I am trying to set search window based on my textbook. But I failed with the error message below. I don't understand the cause although this is just a syntax error. Could you give me some advice?

☆error message

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'

indexapp/controllers/members_controller.rb
```

☆index.html.erb(members controller)

```
<h1>Listing users</h1>
<p>※登録されているメンバーのリストです。</p>

<%= form_tag :action => 'index' do %>
 <div class = "field">
  <%= label_tag 'place', '活動場所：'　%><br />
  <%= text_field_tag 'place' %>
 </div> 
 <div class = "field">
  <%= label_tag 'field', '分野：'　%><br />
  <%= text_field_tag 'field' %>
 </div> 
 <%= submit_tag '検索' %>
<% end %>

<%= @places_field %>
```

☆members controller

```
def index
    if !checklogin? then return end #
      @members = Member.all

      @places_field = Member.where("place = ? AND field = ?", params[:place],   
params[:field])
      render 'members/index'

     #respond_to do |format|
     #  format.html # index.html.erb
     #  format.json
     #end 
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the extra spaces, new line and `then`

```
def index
   if !checklogin? 
      return 
   end 

   @members = Member.all

   @places_field = Member.where("place = ? AND field = ?", params[:place], params[:field])    
   render 'members/index'
end
```

Comment: Thank you. I rewrote and made it.